# Terraform : Error: Missing resource schema from provider. No resource schema found for local_file

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I am using terraform version 0.13.2, provider http://registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v2.1.0 and have the following resource :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

resource "local_file" "test_local_file" {
  content = "This is a test file"
  filename = "test.txt"
}
```

Now when I take only the terraform.tfstate file in another directory and try to destroy this configuration using terraform 1.1.2 in the new directory I get the following error on terraform destroy :

```
│ Error: Missing resource schema from provider
│ 
│ No resource schema found for local_file.
```

What is the fix?

Comment: Can you post the `terraform` block with `required_providers` as well?

Comment: @MarkoE I have updated the question with terraform block

Comment: Ah wait, you said you moved **only** the state file to another directory?

Answer (score 8):

Using terraform v1.1.2, when you try to delete the configuration using only the state file terraform is somehow not able to fetch the local provider.
The fix is to include the `local` provider block in the new directory along with the state file and then perform `terraform init`, `terraform apply`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also ran into this when removing a local_file resource from my configuration. The local_file resource was still present in the state file... which usually would prompt terraform to delete the resource and remove it from the state file since it was no longer part of the configuration. Instead it threw this error. I ended up just using terraform state rm to remove it from the state file.

Answer (score 0):

Error: Missing resource schema from provider

i found the solution as -
find the file with .tfstate extension and edit this as per the requirement. Or delete this file and run terraform init and terraform plan command. issue will be resolved.

Comment: Suggesting to delete a Terraform state file could result in lots of headaches. Make sure you backup your state file before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same issue while trying to run `terraform apply` after removing the *last* resource from tf config, which also came from implicitly required provider (in my case it was *time* provider).

The solution for this was to destroy the state as well:
`terraform destroy [resource id]`

After this, apply should work again.